# MongoDB and Node.js aggregate using $sample isn't returning a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate-functions

I'm new to Nodejs and mongoDB and I'm trying to get an aggregate function running that will select a random document from the database and return it. I've looked all over on the internet to figure out what I'm doing wrong and from what I can see my code looks like it should. For some reason however, when I try printing the result to console, it gives me an aggregation cursor object and I can't find the document I want anywhere within it. Here is my code for the aggregate function.

```
//get a random question
route.get('/question/random', function (req, res) {
database.collection('questions').aggregate(
    [ { $sample: { size: 1} } ],
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
})
```

Comment: I think you write a fine code but maybe typo check that have you write the right name of collection or do collection exist

Comment: I'm certain it exists and is spelled right.

Comment: Increase the size and check what happens

Comment: same thing unfortunately

Comment: `forEach` does iterate over the cursor to print the documents one by one. To get the documents in one go you have to use `.toArray` method. Something like `db.collection('test').aggregate([
   { $sample: { size: 1} }
   ]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs)
  })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [aggregation method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#aggregate) returns [AggregationCursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/AggregationCursor.html) that won't return any documents unless you iterate through it.

For a simple iteration, you can do:

```
database.collection('questions').aggregate([{$sample: {size: 1}}]).forEach(console.log);
```

The `forEach()` method on the cursor will iterate it, and in this example will print it to the console.

Comment: How do i then Access the elements in the for each loop?

Comment: It's just a standard Javascript forEach loop, you attach a function in the callback of forEach. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach for some examples

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach might fail to work in accessing the data since the latest updates return a cursor instead. I think the last part should be something like

```
let cursor = db.collection("questions").aggregate([ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]);
for await (const question of cursor) {
    console.log("question...\n", question);
}
```